# React Website deployed on Heroku that is using Axios with mongoDB. Pc version works perfect but IOS gets network error

Tags: reactjs, heroku, axios

I wrote a website for creating your own drink in React, JS, CSS. I am using Axios for my HTTP calls and Prisma to connect with mongoDB. The local version and deployed Heroku version on PC both connect to the DB and work perfectly but I noticed the deployed version on IOS is getting the following error:

```
ERROR

Network ErrorAxiosError@https://pickyour-poison-d276c8edc8c1.herokuapp.com/static/js/bundle.js:86715:27handleError@https://pickyour-poison-d276c8edc8c1.herokuapp.com/static/js/bundle.js:86101:77
```

This is a snippit of the home page that is getting the error

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Home( { cartItems, setCartItems } ) {
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getOrders() {
          const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/orders")
          setOrders(result.data)
        }
        getOrders()
    }, [])
```

This is my server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import {} from 'dotenv/config'
import './config/database.js'
import path from 'path'
import logger from 'morgan'
import favicon from 'favicon'
import cors from 'cors'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'



const app = express()
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());



const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;


app.use(cors());


app.get('/orders', async function(req, res) {
  const orders = await prisma.order.findMany({
    take: 20,
    orderBy: {
      createdAt: 'desc'
    }
  });
  res.status(200).send(orders);
});

app.post('/orders', async function(req, res) {
  
  const title = req.body.name;
  const glass = req.body.glass;
  const spirits = [];
  req.body.spirits.forEach(spirit => {
    spirits.push(spirit);
  });
  const mixers = [];
  req.body.mixers.forEach(mixer => {
    mixers.push(mixer);
  });
  const garnishes = req.body.garnishes;
  const price = req.body.price;

  console.log(title, glass, spirits, mixers, garnishes, price);


  const order = await prisma.order.create({
    data: {
      title: title,
      glass: glass,
      spirits: spirits,
      mixers: mixers,
      garnishes: garnishes,
      price: price
    }
  });

  res.status(200).send(order);
});




// The following "catch all" route (note the *) is necessary
// to return the index.html on all non-AJAX/API requests
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});


app.listen(3001, () => console.log("listening on port 3001"))
```

I have been looking around and haven't found much on this issue. I was thinking it was to do with the localhost of this line in the axios get but I am not sure:

```
const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/orders")
```

I have tried changing it to:

```
const result = await axios.get("http://https://pickyour-poison-d276c8edc8c1.herokuapp.com/orders")
```

That also did not work.

I have put the contents of my .env in the heroku variables as well, which I think are working since the PC version works.

Looking for recommendations.

Thank you,

I have tried changing the localhost to the application name with no success